NullReferenceException at C# SqlConnection Open
From time to time at my Windows 10 system background program in C#, I get a NullReferenceException at this.connection.Open().
My class:
private SqlConnection connection;
private string connectionString;
private StringBuilder trace = new StringBuilder();
private int counter = 0;

public void InitConnectionIfNeeded()
{
    trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [0]");

    // Check if connection is already established but connection string changed, purge it.
    if (this.connection != null && this.connection.ConnectionString != this.connectionString) 
    {
        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [1]");

        if (this.connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
        {
            trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [2]");
            this.connection.Close();
            trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [2+]");
        }

        this.connection = null;
    }

    // Create instance of SqlConnection object by connection string
    if (this.connection == null)
    {
        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [3]");
        this.connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString);
        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [3+]\nConnectionString: {this.connectionString}");
    }

    // If ConnectionState != Open then open it.
    if (this.connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [4]");

        this.connection.Open();

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [4+]");
    }

    trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} InitConnectionIfNeeded [5]");
}

My code in function:
message = "";
errorStackTrace = "";
success = false;
resultsCount = 0;
results = new DataTable();

try
{
    bool connectionEstablished = false;
    Exception lastException = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        try 
        {
            trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Try InitConnectionIfNeeded Attempt: {i+1}");

            InitConnectionIfNeeded();
            connectionEstablished = true;
            break;
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lastException = ex;
        }
    }

    if(!connectionEstablished) 
    {
        throw lastException;
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [1]");

        cmd.CommandTimeout = (int)queryTimeout;

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [2]");
        
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [3]");

        results.Load(reader);

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [4]");

        resultsCount = results.Rows.Count;

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [5]");

        ChangeDate(results);

        trace.AppendLine($"{counter++}\t{DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")} Get Collection [6]");

        success = true;
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == -2)
{
    message = "The command has timed out.";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    message = ex.Message;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine($"-----------------------\nError at: {DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}");
    sb.Append(this.trace + "\n::\n");
    sb.Append($"ex.Source: {ex.Source}\n");
    sb.Append($"ex.HResult: {ex.HResult}\n");

    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        sb.Append($"ex.InnerExceptionMessage: {ex.InnerException.Message}\n");
        sb.Append($"ex.InnerExceptionGetTypeFullName: {ex.InnerException.GetType().FullName}\n");
        sb.Append($"ex.InnerExceptionStackTrace: {ex.InnerException.StackTrace}\n");
    }

    sb.Append($"ex.GetType: {ex.GetType().FullName}\n");

    if (ex.Data != null && ex.Data.Count > 0)
    {
        sb.Append("ex.Data\n");

        foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in ex.Data)
        {
            sb.Append($"{dictionaryEntry.Key}\t{dictionaryEntry.Value}\n");
        }
    }

    sb.Append($"ex.StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}\n.\n.\n");
    sb.AppendLine("--------------------------------------");
    errorStackTrace = sb.ToString();
}

99% of the time, it works - but sometimes I get this result:
Error at: 2024-07-11 14:27:32
0   2024-07-11 14:27:29.555 Try InitConnectionIfNeeded Attempt: 1
1   2024-07-11 14:27:29.555 InitConnectionIfNeeded [0]
2   2024-07-11 14:27:29.555 InitConnectionIfNeeded [3]
3   2024-07-11 14:27:29.555 InitConnectionIfNeeded [3+]
ConnectionString: Data Source=MYSQLSERVER;Database=DB123;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Timeout=30
4   2024-07-11 14:27:29.555 InitConnectionIfNeeded [4]
5   2024-07-11 14:27:30.558 Try InitConnectionIfNeeded Attempt: 2
6   2024-07-11 14:27:30.558 InitConnectionIfNeeded [0]
7   2024-07-11 14:27:30.558 InitConnectionIfNeeded [4]
8   2024-07-11 14:27:31.560 Try InitConnectionIfNeeded Attempt: 3
9   2024-07-11 14:27:31.560 InitConnectionIfNeeded [0]
10  2024-07-11 14:27:31.560 InitConnectionIfNeeded [4]

::
ex.Source: do3wemmp
ex.HResult: -2147467261
ex.GetType: System.NullReferenceException
ex.StackTrace:    w SQLServerC_.Get_Collection(String query, Decimal queryTimeout, String& message, Boolean& success, Decimal& resultsCount, DataTable& results, String& errorStackTrace)
.
.
--------------------------------------


Full stackTrace:
   w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   w System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   w SQLServerC_.InitConnectionIfNeeded()
   w SQLServerC_.Get_Collection(String query, Decimal queryTimeout, String& message, Boolean& success, Decimal& resultsCount, DataTable& results, String& errorStackTrace)

As you see at string builder trace, my code fill this.connection class field and try to Open connection. Unfortunately Open operation failed three times with 1 second delay between.
This happen only in < 1% of the cases.
Do you have any idea how to deal with this?
I tried:

add loop in the InitConnectionIfNeeded method (better situation but still sometimes throws that NullReferenceException)
add trace

I want to resolve these errors and Open connection with success result.

Its a little weird that you throw a variable called lastException which can be null (so you can actually throw null). That looks suspicious.

Is there some multithreading going on here? Perhaps you need a lock

Seems like a concurrency issue to me. I'd revise this code a bit, referring to the microsoft docs. It is recommended to use SqlConnections with a using statement and open the connection within it. This ensures that the connection is closed once you no longer need it.
This will also help you ensure that you aren't sharing the connection between threads and you avoid long running connections

Mistake #1: caching the SqlConnection object. Never do this. Create it when you need and dispose with using, do not reuse.

Trying to share connections around like this is why you're having issues. SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are all classes implementing the IDisposable interface. Instances of them are all meant to be short-lived, created and disposed of in using scopes as and when they're needed.

Thanks for help. Without caching SqlConnection object, it's starts working.
